# Bluetooth keyboard disconnecting

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, bluetooth, disconnect

Ubuntu 14.04

I have been having issues with my bluetooth keyboard ([Targus Bluetooth Keyboard](http://reviews.targus.com/8826/AKB33US/targus-bluetooth-wireless-keyboard-for-tablets-reviews/reviews.htm)) disconnecting within ten seconds after I stop typing. Bluetooth Manager still shows the device on the list (I am able to connect the device initially), but it appears to be inactive. It then takes up to thirty more seconds for it to respond to a single button press, and usually does not respond at all. Needless to say, this basically renders the keyboard useless and forces me to use a wired keyboard (which is inconvenient in my case).

A possibly related issue is that every time the connection is re-established, I receive a message indicating that the keyboard has 0% battery power. This happens even with brand new batteries.

- WiFi is operating on the 5GHz band; the problem persists even when not using the internet
- My bluetooth mouse has not been having this type of issue
- The keyboard seems to function normally with a Dell laptop running Windows 8

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Same for Ubuntu 17.10 with Microsoft Designer Keyboard. Mouse is working fine, keyboard stops working after a not using it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a similar problem to bug #1098959 , where the power monitor interferes with bluetooth devices.

Comment: So... there is no solution?

Comment: Only the  workaround mentioned in comment 2 of the bug, killing the upowerd and indicator.  You could add yourself to the bug, the more people affected, the more likely it is to be fixed. Include your hardware too.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by this today, but I think there is no real problem.  I think what is happening is that when I don't type anything for a while, the keyboard is temporarily turned off to save power, either by itself of by `upowerd`, and then when I type on it again, it wakes up.  But it doesn't wake up so fast that I don't notice that something has happened.

Once I realized this, no fix was required, just a slight change in my typing habits: if I type on the keyboard and nothing appears, I should wait a second and try again.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS, ubuntu bluetooth could not be set to high fidelity (A2DP).

However, if I momentarily disable WiFi and then reconnect to my headset, high fidelity is possible.

Re-enabling WiFi does not effect the now-enabled high fidelity setting and WiFi appears to be working as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but a workaround working for me so far:

1. On Ubuntu, turn off bluetooth, then reboot
2. Once Ubuntu backs up, kill `upowerd` process
3. Turn on bluetooth
4. (If you use VMs) Also make sure bluetooth is off on VMs
5. Connect bluetooth k/b
6. Open `upowerd` gui (I did it by clicking power indicator on the `Unity`'s rim)

Ubuntu Trusty 64b, Thinkpad k/b EBK-209A.